# How do you get Emacs haskell-mode to find modules in other hs-source-dirs?

Tags: macos, haskell, emacs, haskell-mode

**UPDATE: clarified that this is on Mac OS X**

I'm using Emacs Prelude (which uses **haskell-mode**) on Mac OS X and I've created a project with `stack new hello`.

The project it generates is like this:

- hello:

  - LICENSE
  - Setup.hs
  - hello.cabal
  - stack.cabal
  - app:

    - Main.hs
  - src:

    - Lib.hs
  - test:

    - Spec.hs

If I open **Main.hs** in Emacs it shows this:

```
module Main where

import Lib

main :: IO ()
main = someFunc
```

But **Lib** is underlined as an error and placing my caret there shows this:

```
Could not find module 'Lib'
Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
```

How do you get Emacs haskell-mode to find modules in other hs-source-dirs?

Comment: does `C-c C-l` load it into the REPL? Is `'haskell-process-type` set to `auto`?

Comment: btw: maybe you should update to a current `haskell-mode` - not sure when `stack`-support was included but maybe you got an older version - also: why is there a `stack.cabal`? It's `stack.yaml` right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The greatest horror is that I fixed this by rebooting.

I appear to have triggered it by breaking the path to Stack.  The path changed from my original manual install to `~/Applications/bin/stack` to `~/.local/bin/stack`.  I knew that had changed so I closed and relaunched Emacs, but the problem persisted.

Rebooting fixed it.  This brings me sadness.  I imagine logging out might have worked just as well.

Comment: it was probably only your path-variable ^^ so restarting emacs (really restarting) and/or the shell you used would probably have been fine too (check with `which stack`) ;)

Comment: @Carsten I reproduced it from scratch after. M-x getenv ENT PATH immediately showed the missing path. That was fixable by logout.  Running the interactive shell needed a separate fix in .emacs `(setq exec-path (append exec-path '("/usr/local/bin")))`

Comment: that's strange as emacs should use your existing path (maybe the order is wrong - is pointing `which stack` to the right one) - anyway the most important thing is that it's working for you again ;)

Comment: @Carsten Yep.  It's now solid.  I'm partly conflating things here as that setq step is related to the fact that I'm now using bitemyapp's .emacs and .emacs.d/ from https://github.com/bitemyapp/dotfiles.